# How Can I edit the woocommerce product table at backend to align properly

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

When I install rank maths and other plugin on my WordPress website, and then I go to the product table to edit the product, I get this distortion on the table as a result of one column in the table that displays words vertically. (see image)

How can I correct this?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Go to Woocommerce -> Products.** Then see that there is a menu called **"screen options"** at the top. You can uncheck "SEO Detail" options or some unnecessary things there

Comment: Thanks so much, byarnoldus. I love you so much. It's a simple and common sense solution.